# French comic about a Native American prisoner

Tags: identification-request, french-language, comics

I am looking for a French comic that was published at least 30 years ago.

The story took place in the Wild West, during the American Indian Wars.

There were three main characters: a young man with a horse, an old, half-crazy British soldier who intended to retake the colonies on his own, and a young Native American woman. The soldier tries to fight a group of American soldiers, is humiliated, then tasked by them to take the Native American prisoner to the nearest fort.

On the way, the three of them meet some more Native Americans, and a man who goes crazy when it rains.

At the end, the young man and the young woman flee the fort under attack by the Native Americans, but she gets shot and dies in his arms.

Comment: Nothing seems like an obvious match on [this list](https://www.senscritique.com/liste/Les_Indiens_d_Amerique_du_Nord_en_bande_dessine/2646891#page-1/), but still, please take a look to tell us whether it's definitely not one of these, or to the contrary, if you found it there (in which case please offer it as a self-answer!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comic is [*L'uomo di carta*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27uomo_di_carta_(fumetto)) (1981) / *L'homme de papier* / *The Paper Man*, written and drawn by Milo Manara. So it's not a French comic after all, but an Italian one that was translated into French.

> La storia appartiene al genere western, e svolge in Arizona. A un arzillo vecchietto inglese, con l'ossessione della guerra e delle vecchie uniformi, viene affidato dalle giacche azzurre l'ingrato compito di scortare una prigioniera Sioux a Fort Laramie, per essere presa in custodia. Il vecchio si avvia assieme a un ragazzo biondo incontrato accidentalmente, il quale è diretto nel Maine per ritrovare la sua innamorata Gwendoline, di cui porta gelosamente con sé una foto e che gli vale, da parte della prigioniera indiana Coniglia Bianca, l'appellativo di “uomo di carta” (“se tu ama donna di carta, tu è un uomo di carta!” lo deride la Sioux). Durante il viaggio verso Fort Laramie, al gruppo si unisce un quarto strano personaggio, il “reverendo”, persona mansueta che però, a causa di una sorta di maledizione, diventa violento nei giorni di pioggia.

Google Translate:

> The story belongs to the western genre, and takes place in Arizona. A sprightly old Englishman, obsessed with war and old uniforms, is entrusted by the blue jackets with the thankless task of escorting a Sioux prisoner to Fort Laramie, to be taken into custody. The old man sets off with an accidentally met blond boy who is headed to Maine to find his sweetheart Gwendoline, of whom he jealously carries a photo and which, on the part of the Indian prisoner Coniglia Bianca, holds the nickname of "Paper Man" ("if you love a paper woman, you are a paper!," the Sioux mocks him). During the journey to Fort Laramie, the group is joined by a fourth strange character, the "Reverend", a meek person who, however, due to a sort of curse, becomes violent on rainy days.

("British soldier" ended up being a more useful key word than "Indian prisoner".)